# Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date (in html or ts)

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I am using Ionic2 with Meteor.

I am getting the following error. As far as I can understand from [here](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/), is because I am using `Moments` with a `Date` object. I read from the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/), that I should be doing something like `moment(date)`.

How is this possible in the `html` code I have below?

**Error**

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This
>   is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please
>   refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments: [object Object] Error
>       at Function. (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:101531:106)
>       at configFromString (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103261:33)
>       at configFromInput (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103621:14)
>       at prepareConfig (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103604:14)
>       at createFromConfig (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103571:45)
>       at createLocalOrUTC (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103658:17)
>       at local__createLocal (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:103662:17)
>       at utils_hooks__hooks (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:101262:30)
>       at DateFormatPipe.transform (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:115302:17)
>       at DebugAppView._View_MessagesPage3.detectChangesInternal (MessagesPage.template.js:801:88)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:16169:15)

**html**

```
<div *ngFor="let message of localMessageCursor" class="message-wrapper">
  <div *ngIf="message">
    <div *ngIf="message.changeDate">
      <center><span class="message-datetime">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'}}</span></center>
    </div>
    <div [class]="'message message-' + message.ownership">
      <div class="message-content">local:{{message.content}}</div>
      <span class="time-tick">
    <span class="message-timestamp">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
      <div *ngIf="message.readByReceiver && senderId == message.senderId">
        <span class="checkmark">
          <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
          <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
      </span>
      </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**model**

```
  interface Message {
    _id?: string;
    chatId?: string;
    senderId?: string;
    ownership?: string;
    content?: string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    changeDate?: boolean;
    readByReceiver?: boolean;
  }
```

The supporting **ts** file. You can see it is using a `pipe` to utilize `moments` in the `html`.

```
import { DateFormatPipe } from 'angular2-moment';
pipes: [DateFormatPipe],
```

Comment: I don't see any use of `moment()` in the code presented here. Your message is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Liam, I had a look at that post that you think may be a duplicate, thank you. However, my issue is I don't know how to do it, specific to my situation (i.e. `message.createdAt`).

Comment: Hi Mike, it is coming from:  `{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'}}`. I am using this `pipe` in the `ts` file:  `import { DateFormatPipe } from 'angular2-moment';`

Comment: @Liam, please unmark this as a duplicate.

Comment: [edit] the question to improve it and add information that shows it is not a duplicate. For instance, adding the `angular2` tag and the information about this `angular2-moment` library you're using will go some distance. If you could include the code for the `DateFormatPipe`, even better.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for the advise. I do edit the original post, adding the pipe info, but I don't know how to remove the duplicate flag.

Comment: Editing will put it into a Reopen queue, where 5 people will review to see if it warrants reopening. See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) for more information. Note that the root cause of your error is still the same as in the duplicate; it's just several layers down. You should be able to find the source for the `DateFormatPipe` and debug your code to ensure that the `createdAt` property is indeed a `Date` object when it's passed to the pipe.